# Array getting undefined on state change on Redux

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, filter

I am trying to mutate state by running filter and map methods, when I am returning my array the state is becoming undefined.

```
const getAllApprovedProviderReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
    if(action.type === GET_ALL_APPROVED_PROVIDER) {
        return {
            ...state
        }
    }
    if(action.type === FILTER_BY_FINANCIAL_SERVICES) {
        console.log(action.payload)
        return {
            ...state,
            success: state.success.map((item, index)=> {
                item.servicesOffered.filter(i=>{
                    if(i===action.payload) {
                        return item
                    }
                    else {
                        // console.log(state.success);
                        return item
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
return state;
}
```

At the presentation component the state is changed to undefied.
What I am doing wrong to make state undefined.

Comment: The function you pass to `.map` does not return anything, hence every value is mapped to undefined. `return` doesn't cross function boundaries and the function you pass to `.filter` should return a boolean value. Maybe you don't need `.map` at all, maybe you just need `.filter`. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: state.success is a array of objects and servicesOffered is again an array. I am trying to filter out using servicesOffered

Comment: Can you provide some example data? It's unclear from the code what the result should look like.

Comment: Even in `filter` also even if condition is `true` or `false` you are trying to return the object in fact you just need to return `true` or `false` from Array.filter function.

Comment: `[0:
OrganizationAddress: "asdsadasdasd"
OrganizationName: "Goldman Sachs"
OrganizationRegNumber: "asdasdasdsd"
approved: true
country: "France"
createdOn: "2020-06-12T21:28:11.420Z"
email: "asmdkmaskdmakkk@gmail.com"
fullName: "Goldman Schas"
idType: "asdsadasdsd"
mobileNumber: "4388883434"
partnerId: "0e45e94d-b8bb-464d-b24f-bc079dd0a8d2"
partnerType: "CA(Practioner)"
role: 2
servicesOffered: ["Banking"]]`

Comment: I guess you want `success: state.success.filter(item => item.servicesOffered.includes(action.payload))`.

Comment: item is returning correctly but the state is set as undefined

Comment: *"item is returning correctly but the state is set as undefin"* Uh? If you remove everying from the `.map` callback and just write `success: state.success.map((item, index) => {})` you get the exact same result. You can't really say that "item is returning correctly" because your code doesn't do what you want it to do. See my previous comment for a solution.

Comment: `item.servicesOffered.some()` always returns empty array

Comment: I have changed my suggestion, but of course it's based on the assumption that `action.payload` will be a value found in `servicesOffered`. If that's not the case, maybe tell us what `action.payload` is or just adjust the suggestion as necessary. I asked you to provide example data and you only provided partial information.

Comment: `includes` version works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

The function you pass to `.map` does not return anything, hence every value is mapped to `undefined`. `return` doesn't cross function boundaries and the function you pass to `.filter` should return a boolean value.

---

If you only want to keep the objects which offer a specific service, then you can do that the following way:

```
state.success.filter(item => item.servicesOffered.includes(action.payload))
```

`.filter` will remove every element for which the callback returns `false`.

Using `.map` here doesn't make sense since it will always be a 1:1 mapping between input and output. If you want to reduce the number of elements you have to use `.filter`.

And while it's possible to use `.filter` to test for the presence of a value in an array, there are more specific methods for that, such as `.includes` and `.some`.